# virtualenv and subprocess.call() in mixed Python 2.7/3.3 environment

Tags: python, subprocess, virtualenv, travis-ci

For some functional tests, I invoke a couple of utilities directly from the project directory, using Python's `subprocess.call` (or `check_call` which invokes the latter).  This works well when the libraries (PyYAML in particular) are installed globally.  Running in a virtualenv, such as under Travis-CI, causes problems, especially if the virtualenv is running Python 3.x and the global Python is 2.7.

If both Pythons are 2.7, I still had to inject the location of PyYAML within the virtualenv, using the `env` argument to `subprocess.call`, in order not to cause an ImportError.  However, this doesn't work when the virtualenv is 3.x.  It appears the invoked utility runs outside the virtualenv because its `sys.path` looks as follows:

```
 '/home/travis/build/jmafc/Pyrseas/pyrseas', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg', '/home/travis/build/jmafc/Pyrseas', '/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

Notice the mixture of 2.7 and 3.3 paths, the latter being expressly injected as mentioned above.

Is there some way from either `virtualenv` or in the `subprocess` functions to ensure the subprocess runs "within" the virtualenv?

Comment: Could you show us your code for subprocess.call?

Comment: You can find the code [here](https://github.com/jmafc/Pyrseas/blob/master/pyrseas/testutils.py) in the ``DbMigrateTestCase.create_yaml`` (for example).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you pass in a copy of your environment variables and use the current Python interpreter as the target of the subprocess, the virtualenv environment should be preserved. Something like this:

```
subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'yourscript.py'], env=os.environ.copy())
```

Comment: Thanks, that appears to do the trick in my virtualenv. Now I'll have to see how it fares in Travis-CI.